# Sublime text: Swap line and indent

Tags: sublime-text-2

I recently gave atom a try. Despite being too slow, there was one thing I liked: the way auto indent worked, basically everywhere.

I found [here](https://gist.github.com/twosixcode/1988097) how to make `Paste + Indent the default` in sublime text.

But I'd also like that the:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+up"], "command": "swap_line_up" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+down"], "command": "swap_line_down" },
```

become `swap_line_up_and_indent` so that if I have:

```
console.log('hello');
function() {

}
```

and I `ctrl+shift+down`, I get:

```
function() {
  console.log('hello'); // indented yai!!
}
```

Any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the easiest way to do this (aside from writing a rather extensive plugin) is by [macro](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html). Here is `swap_line_down_and_indent.sublime-macro`:

```js
[
    {
        "command": "swap_line_down"
    },
    {
        "command": "indent"
    }
]
```

and `swap_line_up_and_indent.sublime-macro`:

```js
[
    {
        "command": "swap_line_up"
    },
    {
        "command": "move",
        "args":
        {
            "by": "lines",
            "forward": true
        }
    },
    {
        "command": "indent"
    }
]
```

Save the files in `Packages/User` where `Packages` is the folder opened when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**. Next, edit your custom keymap with the following:

```js
{ 
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+up"], 
    "command": "run_macro_file", 
    "args": 
    {
        "file": "res://Packages/User/swap_line_up_and_indent.sublime-macro"
    } 
},
{ 
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+down"], 
    "command": "run_macro_file", 
    "args": 
    {
        "file": "res://Packages/User/swap_line_down_and_indent.sublime-macro"
    } 
}
```

and you should be all set. There are a couple caveats, though. These macros will only indent one level, so you may need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to indent the line further. Also, it is assumed that the line to be indented is the lower line after the `swap_line_[up|down]` command is run.

Comment: Thanks for beautiful answer. The macro itself did not work as suggested, but I fixed it by doing: `[
    {
        "command": "swap_line_down"
    },
    {
        "command": "reindent",
        "args": {"single_line": false}
    }
]`. Same for going up.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger that worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as well by using the 'Chain of Command' package. Install the package and just add the following to the user key bindings file:

```
{
   "keys": ["ctrl+super+up"], 
   "command": "chain", 
   "args": {
     "commands": [
       ["swap_line_up"],
       ["reindent", {"single_line": false}]
     ],
   },
 },
{
  "keys": ["ctrl+super+down"], 
  "command": "chain", 
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      ["swap_line_down"],
      ["reindent", {"single_line": false}]
    ],
  },
}
```